# How do I attach optional attributes to values?

Tags: haskell, types, variant

I want to store a list of "things" which can have some optional extra attributes attached to them. Each thing can have one or more attributes. And different attributes are of different types.

I want to be able to create literal lists of these things concisely in code. But I'm having trouble seeing how to get this past the type system because tuples allow mixtures of types but are fixed length, while lists are variable length but one type.

This is a toy example of what I want to be able to do  :

```
things = [
   Thing 1 RED,
   Thing 2 RED LARGE,
   Thing 3 BLUE SMALL,
   Thing 4 SMALL,
   Thing 5 BLUE DOTTED
]
```

etc.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: You you give a slightly less toy-ish example, at least roughly the application you're aiming at?

Comment: It's a music application. The "Things" are really Chords and the optional attributes are really hints at particular kinds of transformation (add a 7th, remove the root, spread across two octaves etc.) I didn't want to go into too much detail because I don't want people saying "to do music, use Haskore" etc. This is a learning exercise so I'm using it to get an understanding of the principles beyond any particular application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, rather than storing the attributes as given, you should store the resultant *properties* of a chord with these attributes. One simple (but not really nice, musically) solution would be, storing only the final pitches:

```
newtype Pitch = Pitch {midiNote :: Int}

a, as, bb, b, bs, c, cs, db, d, ds, eb, e, es, f, fs, gb, g, gs, ab :: Pitch
[ a, as,bb, b,bs, c,cs,db, d,ds,eb, e,es, f,fs,gb, g,gs,ab] = map Pitch
 [55,56,56,57,58,58,59,59,60,61,61,62,63,63,64,64,65,66,66]

type Chord = [Pitch]

minor :: Pitch -> Chord
minor (Pitch fund) = map (Pitch . (fund+)) [0, 3, 7]

seventh :: Pitch -> Chord
seventh (Pitch fund) = map (Pitch . (fund+)) [0, 4, 7, 10]

spread :: Chord -> Chord
spread = sort
 . zipWith (\octShift (Pitch note) -> Pitch $ note + 12 * octShift) $ cycle [0,1]
```

To be used as e.g.

```
chords :: [Chord]
chords = [ minor e, seventh d, minor e, minor a, seventh b, spread $ minor e ]
```

A more sophisticated approach might actually store the information about a chord in a more musically meaningful way:

```
data Chord = Chord { fundamental :: Pitch
                   , gender :: Maybe ChordGender
                   , ExtraNotes :: [AddNote]
                   , OctaveShifts :: [Int]
                   }

data ChordGender = Major | Minor
data AddNote = AddNote { roughInterval :: Int, intervalIsMajor :: Bool }

major :: Pitch -> Chord
major fund = Chord fund (Just Major) [] []

sus4 :: Pitch -> Chord
sus4 fund = Chord fund Nothing [AddNote 4 False] []

spread :: Chord -> Chord
spread ch@(Chord _ _ _ shifts)
  = ch{shifts = cycle [0,1]}
```

This can be used in much the same way, but is more versatile.

If you don't like giving the attributes as prefix functions, you can do [as the diagrams package, with](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.0.1/docs/Diagrams-Util.html#v%3a-35-)

```
infixl 8 #
(#) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
(#) = flip ($)
```

to write

```
chords = [ c # major
         , g # sus4
         , g # major
         , a # minor
         , f # major # spread
         , g # sus4  # spread
         , g # major # spread
         , c # major # spread
         ]
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's say Chords are collections of Notes.

```
data Note = A | Bb | B | C | ...
```

But also with optional sets of Annotations

```
data Ann = Seventh | Sus2 | Split | ...
```

We can model Chords thus as

```
data Chord = Chord { notes :: [Note]
                   , anns :: [Ann]
                   }
```

We can build an entire vocabulary this way

```
maj :: Note -> Chord
ann :: Ann -> Chord -> Chord
transpose :: Int -> Note -> Note
transposeChord :: Int -> Chord -> Chord
```

And then build our list like so

```
chords = [
  ann Seventh (maj C)
, ann Split (ann Sus2 (maj A))
]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to implement [heterogeneous collections](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Heterogenous_collections) in Haskell, but using a list of arbitrary values of arbitrary types is probably more flexibility than you need, and more trouble than it's worth.  You're probably better off creating one type with an expressive set of possible values, and using a homogeneous collection of that.

Your example attributes appear to fall into a set of known categories:  color (e.g. RED, BLUE), size (e.g. LARGE, SMALL), and what I'll call "texture" (e.g. DOTTED).  A `Thing` doesn't necessarily have an attribute in each category, but I'll assume that it shouldn't have more than one attribute in the *same* category — it doesn't make sense for a single `Thing` to be both LARGE and SMALL.

You could represent these categories as algebraic data types:

```
data Color = Red
           | Blue

data Size = Large
          | Small

data Texture = Dotted
```

and combine them with a data structure:

```
data ThingAttributes = ThingAttributes {
  thingColor :: Maybe Color,
  thingSize :: Maybe Size,
  thingTexture :: Maybe Texture
}
```

Now you can just associate a single `ThingAttributes` value with each `Thing`.

If you *do* want to allow multiple attributes in the same category (e.g. having a `Thing` that's both LARGE and SMALL), you can use another algebraic data type to bring all the category types together:

```
data ThingAttribute = ColorAttribute Color
                    | SizeAttribute Size
                    | TextureAttribute Texture
```

and then associate a `Set ThingAttribute` — or simply a `[ThingAttribute]` if you don't mind duplicates of the same attribute — with each `Thing`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going with the other solution but I learned a lot from this.