# Using defined data types in other data types

Tags: haskell, types

Following on from my question here :  [How do I attach optional attributes to values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22133995/how-do-i-attach-optional-attributes-to-values)

I'm trying to define a Haskell representation of music.

I'd like to do something this :

```
data Chord = Chord Int Modality [Annotate] deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

which, as I understand defines a new type which is a Chord.

And then I want to be able to add Chords amongst other events to a Score such that

```
data Event = Note Int | Chord Int Modality [Annotate] | Rest
```

However, the compiler says I'm trying to define Chord twice.

So, is there a way to use an earlier defined data type inside a new data type definition? What I'm doing looks, to me, more or less like the classic Tree definition :

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

which works OK. So why is it ok to use "Tree" in this example, but not "Chord" in mine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not about defining a *type* twice, but about defining the *constructor* `Chord` twice. You probably want

```
type Note = Int

data Event = NoteEvent Note | ChordEvent Chord | Rest
```

Alternatively, you can leave `Event` as is, but there you've basically inlined the entire definition of the `Chord` data type, so you don't need that anymore then.

Answer (score 4):

```
data Chord = Chord Int Modality [Annotate] deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

Note `Chord` is used twice here. The two occurrences are used for two different things.

```
data Chord =                       -- This one defines a new data type
     Chord Int Modality [Annotate] -- This one defines a new data constructor
```

It's OK to give the two things the same name because they exist in different namespaces.

```
data Event = Note Int | Chord Int Modality [Annotate] | Rest
```

Now you are trying to define another data constructor named Chord, which is a no-no. Data constructors must be unique across all data types in the module. If you want to *use* the `Chord` type here, use it like this:

```
data Event = NoteEvent Int    | -- A new data constructor, then optionally type(s)
             ChordEvent Chord | -- A new data constructor, then optionally type(s)
             OtherEvent         -- A new data constructor, then optionally type(s)
```